# Opengl convert between older and newer version

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

Hy, i change LWGLJ 2.03 to 2.83 and there is problem why i get this error:

```
GLApp.run(): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: FloatBuffer is not direct
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: FloatBuffer is not direct
    at org.lwjgl.BufferChecks.checkDirect(BufferChecks.java:139)
    at org.lwjgl.BufferChecks.checkBuffer(BufferChecks.java:259)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glMultMatrix(GL11.java:2308)
    at glmodel.CarModel.drawWheel(CarModel.java:131)
    at physics.Physics.render(Physics.java:649)
    at awesomejeep.AwesomeJeep.drawObjects(AwesomeJeep.java:352)
    at awesomejeep.AwesomeJeep.render(AwesomeJeep.java:271)
    at glapp.GLApp.draw(GLApp.java:554)
    at glapp.GLApp.run(GLApp.java:166)
    at awesomejeep.AwesomeJeep.main(AwesomeJeep.java:84)

I get error in this line:
GL11.glMultMatrix(FloatBuffer.wrap(glMat));
```

I realy dont know whats wrong

Comment: You cannot wrap another buffer and pass that to LWJGL's functions that take arrays / pointers. See [this article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#direct) for a more thorough description of direct vs. non-direct buffers. It basically boils down to the efficiency of passing the buffer around, a direct buffer does not have to be copied repeatedly and is much more friendly when interfacing with APIs that pass memory pointers around.

Comment: but what is wrong with dis code, what i must change ?

Comment: I have not seen your actual code, but I think you can pass `glMat` directly (without wrapping it). If it is a `ByteBuffer`, then calling `asFloatBuffer (...)` will give you a ***view*** of the buffer, which ***is*** direct.